# If I share a google calendar to someone, will that person notified automatically for the events created in that?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to create and share a google calendar with a person. Also I want to notify the person for the events I create in that calendar automatically. So, if I share a google calendar to someone, will that person notified automatically for the events created in that? If not how to set the notification for the person without need for adding that person as a guest to the events in that calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You should explicitly invite the person in the event for him to be notified. The documentation doesn't mention such feature yet. If you would like to invite the person, include them using [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).

Comment: Thanks for the information. But as a direct user of Google Calendar, the Events.insert seems to be the programmatic way, which I will not be using.